# localforage with Require.js

Tags: requirejs, localforage

I'm trying to load the [localforage](https://mozilla.github.io/localForage/) lib with require.js but can't get it work. Here's my require.js config:

main.html:

```
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/xyz/js/lib/require-2.1.22.js">  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/xyz/js/main.js?version=1.0.0"></script>
</body>
```

main.js:

```
var appVersion = "1.0.0";
requirejs.config({      
    baseUrl: "../js",
    paths: {
        jquery: "lib/jquery-1.12.1",
        jquery_caret:  "lib/jquery.caret-1.5.1",
        lodash: "lib/lodash-4.5.1",
        localforage: "lib/localforage"
    },      
    shim: {
        jquery_caret: ["jquery"]
    },
    urlArgs: "version=" + appVersion
});

var scriptSources = ["jquery", "jquery_caret", "localforage", "lodash"];    
require(scriptSources, function() {
    //all scripts loaded
});
```

But when I later ty to use localforage like this

```
localforage.setDriver(localforage.INDEXEDDB).then(function() {
    console.log("Hi there");
});
```

it is always undefined. Btw. with [Dexie](http://dexie.org/) I'm having the same problem.
And when I add the following code from the README

```
define(['localforage'], function(localforage) {
  // As a callback:
  localforage.setItem('mykey', 'myvalue', console.log);

  // With a Promise:
  localforage.setItem('mykey', 'myvalue').then(console.log);
});
```

I'm getting the error from requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
But what does it mean ? Could someone please explain it to me ? I don't understand it really.

Comment: In the meantime it seems to me that I have to change the above define-call from "define(['localforage'], function(localForage) " to "define('localforage', ['localforage'], function(localForage) ". Now the call is not anonymus anymore. But 'localforage' is still undefined !?

Comment: if someone else is interested in I've got it working by using the solution from here even I haven't used the minified version: https://github.com/mozilla/localForage/issues/58

Answer (score -1):

You can try out the examples of the repo and specifically [this one](https://github.com/localForage/localForage/blob/master/examples/main.js).
In more details the complete `main.js` file would look like this:

```js
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        localforage: 'path/to/dist/localforage'
    }
});
define(['localforage'], function(lf) {
    lf.ready().then(function() {
        var key = 'STORE_KEY';
        var value = 'What we save offline';

        lf.setItem(key, value).then(function() {
            console.log('SAVING', value);

            return lf.getItem(key);
        }).then(function(readValue) {
            console.log('READING', readValue);
        });
    });
});
```

Also, the `getItems` plugin has [an example](https://github.com/localForage/localForage-getItems/blob/master/examples/main.js) that also seems similar to yours.